# hive or map reduce logic

Tags: sql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have a table

```
hour minute   level   status device_id date
0    12       100     notChar A        2016/25/4
0    07       100     notChar B        2016/25/4
9    12       100     notChar C        2016/25/4
0    19       99      notChar A        2016/25/4
0    12       100     notChar B        2016/25/4
0    15       99      notChar B        2016/25/4
```

This kind of data, i want to find the difference in time when level drops by one for every device and at the end return (dif in minute,count for that difference) per device eg(3,5) here 3 is difference in minute and 5 is no. of time level drop in 3 min. 
Can some one help me how can i do it with hive query or map reduce program

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want to do. How do you calculate those numbers exactly?

Comment: Take device A first level is 100 at 12 minute the second level drop of one 99 at 19 minute difference is 7 min count is 1. After dis calculation the output for A is (7,1). Similarly for B the first output is (8,1). Now for A device this calculation will go until the level drops till 0 ,and till zero there will be many similar minute difference and many different, so for similar minute difference the counter is there . at the end want output for every devices

Comment: Still its not clear... You mean devise wise level wise count difference ? Have you ever tried with hive by loading data in table. You know the problem statement and imagine if its achievable with query then go with Hive. For afore-mentioned problem statement can you add the query which you are thinking in the question itself? Moreover, if some intermediate processing or translation is needed then you have to choose map-reduce otherwise if you are able to write a single query then go with hive.